# Getting background color of canvas in hex format

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

How can i get the background color of canvas in hex format in fabric.js? when i use canvas.backgroundColor, it returns object and color in rgb format.

Answer (score 1):

there's a trick to easily convert from any css format to hex : use a dummy `context2d`, set its `fillStyle`, then read it again : it's now hex ! :

```
function convertToHex(nonHexColorString) {
  var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = nonHexColorString;
  return ctx.fillStyle;
}

console.log(convertToHex('rgb(0,0,0)'); // -->> output is #000000
```

cache the `context2d` if speed matters :

```
function convertToHex(nonHexColorString) {  
  var ctx  = convertToHex.dummyContext2d;
  if (!ctx) {
      ctx = convertToHex.dummyContext2d = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = nonHexColorString;
  return ctx.fillStyle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay in fabricjs domain you can do:

```
var color = new fabric.Color(nonHexString);
```

then...

```
color.toRgb();
color.getAlpha();
color.toHsl();
color.toHex();
```

and some more.

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Color.html